# sprintf changing the number format

Tags: php, printf

I'm having a problem with `sprintf()`, using it to store a mysql query into a var to use it later.

just to inform, I'm using adodb library for database related operations.

being `$value=25.5` and `$id=5` for example, i have something like

```
$value = number_format($baseValue, 2, ".", "");

$query = sprintf("Insert into table_name (id, value) values (%d, $.02f)", $id, $value);
$db->Execute($query);
```

there's a condition before this that decides if there is another $query being made before this one. if that first query doesn't run this one runs ok being the query

```
Insert into table_name (id, value) values (5, 25.50)
```

but if the first query runs then i get an error on this one because the query turns out as

```
Insert into table_name (id, value) values (5, 25,50)
```

i tried to print `$value` just right before the `sprintf()` and it still has the right format, why on earth is this happening and how do i solve it?

**Edit**: $value isn't even used or changed until this moment

Comment: The two 'Insert' code examples appear to be identical. Is this intentional?

Comment: no one of them has value separated by dot and another one by comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically doing a equivalent number to string conversion twice, first with `number_format()` and then with `printf()` and the `%f` modifier. Replacing `$.02f` with `%s` should be enough.

The reason why `printf()` is not generating a valid English format number is because it's using the regional settings (see [setlocale()](http://php.net/setlocale) for further info). Given that SQL expects a fixed format, it's more reliable to use `number_format()`.

**Update:** The [ADOdb library](http://adodb.sourceforge.net/) seems to support prepared statemens. They are normally a simpler and more robust mechanism than injecting values into your SQL code:

```
$rs = $DB->Execute("select * from table where key=?",array($key));
while (!$rs->EOF) {
    print_r($rs->fields);
    $rs->MoveNext();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stick some single quotes around your values. The `25,50` will be interpreted as two fields, for a start (and I'm pretty sure mySQL won't like 25.50 without quotes either.

```
$query = sprintf("Insert into table_name (id, value) values ('%d', '$.02f')", $id, $value);
```

Will result in:

```
Insert into table_name (id, value) values ('5', '25.50')
```

Comment: value is decimal so adding single quotes arround it will result in a mysql error

Comment: It shouldn't, I think. I didn't think it would, so I've just tested it myself, and it's OK. e.g. `create table test (id int, value decimal(6, 3));`, `insert into test (id, value) values ('5', '25.50');`, `select * from test;` -- returns the values 5, and 25.500 on my system (MySQL 5.1.41)

Comment: you are correct, i had tried it and error still was from the comma.

"Incorrect decimal value: '15,2' for column 'value'"